# Seaborn factorplot

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to create a factor plot but I am not able to change the kind of it from point to bar. How do we do that?

The codes used are

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 %matplotlib inline
 sns.catplot('Sex',kind="bar",data=titanic_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) has the exact example you are looking for. Following the documentation, if you run the below lines, it should generate the bar plot shown.

[image: bar plot generated from the code]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot("alive", col="deck", 
                col_wrap=3, data=titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()], 
                kind="count", height=2.5, aspect=.8)
```

The important argument to note here is `kind="count"`.

Comment: Thankyou for help!!

Comment: Is there anyway to `unhide` the index `yes - no` in when a plot is below ?

Comment: Seems like it may not be possible directly with Seaborn. But you can do that through editing each individual axis. After you call the plot function, `for ax in g.axes:`, you can try `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)`