# Jupyter: How do I prevent matplotlib figures from being automatically shown?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter

I like to only show a matplotlib figure with an explicit `show(fig)`. But Jupyter automatically shows all created figures.

This [link](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-display-plots-only-after-plt-show-in-jup-notebook/2863/2) has a workaround, but it is essentially just capturing all the output of a cell. I don't want to do that.

Related:

- [https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#:~:text=auto-show%20in%20jupyter%20notebooks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#:%7E:text=auto-show%20in%20jupyter%20notebooks)

PS: I am actually using `seaborn`, not matplotlib directly.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.ioff()` before defining any figure object? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949684/7789963

Comment: You can also specify the magic command ```%%capture``` at the beginning of the Jupyter cell. This will prevent all output from that cell

Answer (score 1):

Using `plt.ioff` [disables interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ioff.html#matplotlib-pyplot-ioff) and storing figure in a variable won't display any output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 

plt.ioff()
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

# Load an example dataset with long-form data
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

# Plot the responses for different events and regions
fig = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
             hue="region", style="event",
             data=fmri)
```

But using `plt.show()` reverses the effect and show the output figure:

```
# Import modules here
plt.ioff()

# Set theme and load data here
fig = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
             hue="region", style="event",
             data=fmri)

plt.show()
```

How the Jupyter Notebook output looks like when the above code is used:

[image]

---

The code for plotting the Timeseries plot comes from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html).